# Приглашать или Пригласить?

Tags: перевод, грамматика, вид

Скажите пожалуйста какая разница между: Приглашать и Пригласить?

Есть ли разница?

When would you use either one of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are two aspects of the same verb:

1. Imperfective aspect: `Приглашать`.
2. Perfective aspect: `Пригласить`.

More info and examples: [External link](http://russianstepbystep.com/load/1-1-0-51).

Answer (score 2):

The difference in usage.

1."**Пригласить**" means to invite somebody **just once** (on some occasion).

```
Она пригласила его на свадьбу.

Позвольте пригласить вас на танец.
```

2."**Приглашать**" is used in most other cases.

**(a)** somebody was invited numerous times, each time, etc.

```
Каждый год я приглашал её на Рождество.
```

**(b)** in some negative expressions

```
Он пришёл в гости, хотя я его не приглашал.
```

(it is also possible to say "не пригласил" here but the version above adds a bit of emphasis, like 'I can't remember inviting him', 'I definitely did't invite him')

**(c)** in case where the invitation wasn't accepted

```
Я его приглашал, но он отказался от приглашения.
```

(like, he 'failed to invite' that person, maybe even tried it twice, etc.)

**(d)** when speaking about past days (maybe once, but long ago)

```
Я в своё время даже приглашал его на охоту.
```